# Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; using python mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql

I have a table as follows:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`article` (
     `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pid` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   `html` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `text` LONGTEXT NOT NULL,
    `date` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `url` (`url`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

My insert operation using mysqldb in python is:

```
self.cursor.execute(\
            "insert into article ( pid ,date, html, text)\
            values (%s, %s, %s, %s)",
            ( item['pid'],item['pub_date'], item['body_html'], item['body_text'])
            )
```

It gives me following error when i include body_text. It works fine without body_text.
body_text is a text field.

```
Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near  '), 'Known as \\\"burneshas,\\\" this is a group of Albanian women who, for vario' at line 1
```

Comment: Did you sanitize `body_text`? Could be a SQL injection.

Comment: yeah, i did this two, 
item['body_text'] = ' '.join(item['body_text'] ).encode('utf-8')
item['body_text'] = self.conn.escape_string(item['body_text'])

Comment: @Jashaszun: the OP is using SQL parameters, where the *database adapter* sanitises the inputs.

Comment: I fail to see how this specific code would produce the SQL exception shown; are you certain it is this line that is throwing the exception? Did you change the line but not restart your program?

Comment: ichecked with each and every field. mysql version is 5.5

Comment: Are you connecting to the right `db` ?